# How to find odd solutions only for Pell's equation $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I find only the odd solutions for [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation): $$x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$$ Specifically where $x$ is odd (but $y$ may be even or odd).
Is there a way to generate the odd solutions to $x$, and can they be finite?

Comment: What is wrong with generating all the solutions, and then disregarding the ones where $x$ is even?

Comment: @Aaron but aren't there infinite number of solutions ??
thus I cannot know when to stop and whether there will be a new odd solution on a specific interval .

Comment: But surely the parity of the $x$’s is periodic, no matter what $D$ is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the standard algorithm for solving Pells equation, you find a linear recurrence for the $n$-th solution $x_n, y_n$. These formulas are not too difficult to work out by hand, and originate from $x_n + \sqrt{D}y_n = (x_1+\sqrt{D}y_1)^n$ where $x_1,y_1$ is the basic solution. The resulting formula seems to be:
$$  x_{n} = a x_{n-1} + D b y_{n-1} \\
    y_{n} = a y_{n-1} + b x_{n-1}
$$
where $(a,b) = (x_1,y_1)$.

This in particular means that parity of $x_{n+1},y_{n+1}$ is determined only by parity of $x_n, y_n$. Thus, the parity is periodic, with period at most $4$. You can just write down the lowest couple of solutions, and use this to determine how long the period is, and which terms you need to select. If $x_n,y_n$ is the first pair with the same parity as $x_1,y_1$, then the period is just $n-1$, and the solutions with $x$ odd are just these of the form $k (n-1) + m$ with $k$ is an integer and $1 \leq m < n$ such that $x_m$ is odd. In particular, either $x$ is never odd, or it is odd infinitely often.

Comment: In fact, it's pretty easy to see that $x_2=x_1^2+Dy_1^2$ is always odd, and $y_2=2x_1y_1$ is clearly always even. So the period is at most 2.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all notice that **if $D$ is even** (and $x,y \in
     \mathbb{Z}$), then $x^2 = D y^2 + 1$ is odd, and therefore $x$ is always odd and $y$ is always even.
- On the other hand, **if $D$ is odd**, we can only have:

  1) $x_1$ even and $y_1$ odd, or

  2) $x_1$ odd and $y_1$ even,

  where $(x_1, y_1)$ is the fundamental solution.

  The recurrence formula for the $n$-th solution is: \begin{align} x_{n} &=
     x_1 x_{n-1} + D y_1 y_{n-1}\\ y_{n} &= x_1 y_{n-1} + y_1 x_{n-1}
     \end{align} Therefore, **if $x_1$ is even and $y_1$ is odd**, then
  $x_{n}$ is even (odd) and $y_{n}$ is odd (even) if $x_{n-1}$ is odd
  (even) and $y_{n-1}$ is even (odd). That is, $x_2$ is odd and $y_2$
  is even, $x_3$ is even and $y_3$ is odd etc. So we have oscillation
  of the parity with period equal to 2.

  Otherwise, **if $x_1$ is odd and $y_1$ is even**, then $x_{n}$ is odd and 
  $y_{n}$ is even, $\forall n$.